# Are the tagin considered part of the letter itself?

Tags: halacha, safrus, tagin

When writing a Torah, each letter must be written according to a specific shape / form that is defined for each letter. Certain letters contain *[tagin](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14197-tagin)* (crowns). Are these tagin considered part of the definition of the letter form / shape itself?  When a sofer writes one of the letters that have the tagin, is he required to put those tagin there because the rules of how the letter must be drawn include instructions and requirements for drawing it with the tagin?

Applications of this question:

1 - If the *tagin* are part of the definition of the letter and the Sofer does not include them, would that disqualify the Torah, since he is not writing the shape of the letters correctly?

2 - In the written Torah there are 2 upside down *nun*s - one before Bamidbar 10:35 and one after Bamidbar 10:36.

[Tikkun Sofrim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39141&st=&pgnum=182) (Tel Aviv 57725) shows the upside down nuns with the tagin ("crowns") on top. If the tagin are included within the definition of the shape of the letter, then if the nun is turned upside down, shouldn't the tagin be on the bottom rather than the top.

**Note:** Thanks to DoubleAA for pointing out that in the drawing it is backwards, not upside down. There may be different permissible interpretations on how the Nun is allowed to be drawn, here. I know that in many Sifrei Torah, I have seen it upside down, but I don't know if the tagin are drawn on top or on the bottom.

Comment: In that version the Nuns are flipped about the vertical axis not the horizontal one. No one ever said they are upside down.

Comment: See ShA OC 36 .

Comment: @DoubleAA It's hard to tell when viewing a scanned document! When comparing the 2nd nun to the nun in "uvenucho" it does look upside down. But the first one looks backwards. I can't really tell. I'm gong to edit my question, as I believe that there are various opinions on how to draw the nun.

Comment: @DoubleAA OC 36 seems to answer. Why not make it one?

Comment: DanF, those are halachically considered to be "reversed" (The term being nun-hafucha). Furthermore, the nunim-hafuchim are kind of a separate category from the traditional א–ת alephbet.

Comment: It answers if it's pasul or not, not if it's part of the letter or not (AFAICT)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt No the term is nun-menuzeret "strange" "isolated"

Comment: @DoubleAA, I have always been told that the term was "nun-hafucha." FWIW, I have heard this from sofrim and my father, who happens to be our schul's go-to baal koreh. Also see this link: http://www.sofer.co.uk/html/nun_hafucha.html

Comment: A thought: there's discussion about zayin with a short leg where it's as small as a yud. No-one (AFAIK) says that we should look at the taggin should help decide whether it's a zayin or yud. (But perhaps we worry that it's a yud with extra taggin.)

Answer (score 5):

[Emes l'Yaakov - #17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19343&st=&pgnum=102&hilite=) & [Dinim Uminhagim](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31765&st=&pgnum=29&hilite=) both say that when Tagin are missing from the Torah is not considered Pasul, and one does not have to take out a different Torah, yet one should not read from it until repaired.

Comment: So are they part of the letter itself or not?

Comment: @DoubleAA, if the a Torah that lacks them is not considered passul, they can't be, as we know that a Torah in which a portion of a letter is missing, the Torah is passul.

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand your preciseness. But, Noach's answer and what you cited in OC 36 seems to arrive at a logical conclusion that the tagin is not part of the letter. If you read the language of OC, he uses a verb form stating "you must 'crown' the letters". I.e. the letters are there already, and you have to add 'crowns' to them.

Comment: @Noach it still has tzuras ha'os

Comment: @user6591, which still has the tzurah, the letter with or without the taggin?

Comment: @Noach without. A child will still read it as a zayin even without tagin. So it's a kosher letter.

Comment: @DanF You may understand my preciseness, but I'm just echoing yours even without understanding it. What does it even mean for something to be 'part of the letter itself'? I don't understand what that means.

Comment: @user6591 But you can't erase the taggim on a Shem haShem (eg. שדי). What about making taggim through chok tochos? or adding them shelo kisidran in a mezuza? Frankly, if they aren't part of the letter, then isn't that a problem of mukaf gvil?

Comment: @Double I'm not discussing erasing lichatchila.

Comment: @user6591 We're discussing if something is "part of the letter itself". Erasing seems to be a useful metric for that.

Comment: @Double the OP is decidedly not discussing that.

Comment: @DanF You should always edit to clarify your question, but i still don't know what you are asking. Are you asking if a sofer should write taggim? What defines a detail as 'part' or 'not part' of 'the letter itself'? The requirement to write it? Invalidity if it's not written? If it requires sanctification when written in a Divine Name? If it can be erased when part of a Divine name? Some other metric (mukkaf gvil, chok tochos, etc.)?

Comment: @DoubleAA, R' Melech Michaels (mezuzadepot.com) discusses in one of his blogs that you can add them on a mezuza without an issue of being shelo kesidran, according to his rav, R' Avraham Tzvi Wosner of the Vaad Mishmereth Sta"m.

Comment: @DoubleAA I edited the question. Please inform me if the question needs further editing.

Answer (score 0):

There are three kinds of standard  tagin.
Triples "shatnez gatz" tagim on the letters Shin Ayin Tes Nun Zayin Gimmel Zayin 
Single on the letters bais daled hay kuf
The single tag on the letter "YUD" is considered part of the letter and if it is missing then it is pasul

Comment: Also the Makel on a Chet. (And taggim of lamed and pei and alef. When it comes down to it, it's really just mem kaf tav samekh vav resh that don't ordinarily have anything.)